# How to find out the number of CPUs in Go lang?

Tags: go, system, cpu-cores

Is there a simple way to find out the number of CPU's on a local machine using Go lang?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Golang: how to verify number of processors on which a Go program is running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13234749/golang-how-to-verify-number-of-processors-on-which-a-go-program-is-running)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

http://play.golang.org/p/cuaf2ZHLIx

```
package main

import (  
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(runtime.NumCPU())
}
```