# What is the runtime api to provide number of logical processors?

Tags: multithreading, go

Below UNIX command:

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              4
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  2
Socket(s):           1
```

shows,

```
  CPU(s):              4
  Thread(s) per core:  2
```

which is 4 X 2 = 8 logical processors. Correct me.

---

Below is another Linux command:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
....
cpu cores   : 2
.....
processor   : 1
.....
cpu cores   : 2
.....
processor   : 2
.....
cpu cores   : 2
.....
processor   : 3
.....
cpu cores   : 2
.....
$
```

---

But the below program shows only 4 logical processors:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(runtime.GOMAXPROCS(0))   // gives 4
    fmt.Println(runtime.NumCPU())        // gives 4   
}
```

---

Output:

```
$ go install github.com/myhub/cs61a
$ bin/cs61a 
4
4
code$
```

---

More details:

```
$ go version
go version go1.14.1 linux/amd64
$ uname -a
Linux mohet01-ubuntu 4.15.0-99-generic #100-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 22 20:32:56 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

[Documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#NumCPU) says,

> NumCPU returns the number of logical CPUs usable by the current process.

---

My understanding is,

Go scheduler creates OS threads(`M`) which will be equivalent to number of logical processors.

Why runtime api does not give value as 8?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13245047/3317808

Comment: What version of Go is this? It looks like this could potentially be a defect in the runtime.

Comment: @Adrian `1.14` I edited query with `go version` output.

Comment: The line "CPU(s): 4" in the output of lscpu is the number of logical CPUs. You can also see this in the line "On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3" which says that the logical cores 0, 1, 2 and 3 are currently online (currently available). You can also try running the following in a shell to get the number of physical cores: `grep 'cpu cores' /proc/cpuinfo | uniq`

Comment: @nussjustin Query edited with required command output

Comment: To my understanding based on what you're showing it should be reporting 8 logical cores on 4 physical cores.

Comment: @Adrian Further, OS threads(`M`) should be created equivalent to number of logical cores. Is that correct?

Comment: What @nussjustin wrote. `lscpu` also outputs the Sockets, and Cores per socket. Multiply those to get the total number of cores. Multiply that with Threads per core. That's the number of logical processors, which is `CPU(s)`.

Comment: @icza Query edited... `sockets:1` & `cores per socket :2`

Comment: You have 1 socket with 2 cores, and 2 threads per core, which is 4 logical processors. I don't see how you get to 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to all of your listings above, you have:

- two cores per socket
- and one socket

which means you have only two CPU cores.  However, you also have:

- two threads per core

which means your two CPUs *can* run up to four threads simultaneously (with [some potential drawbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading#Drawbacks), but at least in most cases this should offer significantly more computing power than using two threads total).

Since that's the actual hardware limit, the fact that Go computes the number of threads to use as 4 seems correct.

(I think the reason you are counting to eight is that you are assuming that each of the "cpus" that Linux reports supports two threads.  That is not the case: there are only two physical cores, but each supports two threads, so Linux reports this as four "cpus".)