# Why do we need to call runtime.Gosched after call to atomic.AddUint64 and other similar atomic ops?

Tags: multithreading, go, atomic

Going through *[Go by Example: Atomic Counters](https://gobyexample.com/atomic-counters)*. The code example calls `runtime.Gosched` after calling `atomic.AddUint64`.

`atomic.AddUint64` is called to

> [ensure that this goroutine doesn’t starve the scheduler](https://gobyexample.com/mutexes)

Unfortunately, I am finding the explanation not so meaty and satisfying.

I tried running the sample code (comments removed for conciseness):

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"
import "sync/atomic"
import "runtime"

func main() {

    var ops uint64 = 0

    for i := 0; i < 50; i++ {
        go func() {
            for {
                atomic.AddUint64(&ops, 1)

                runtime.Gosched()
            }
        }()
    }

    time.Sleep(time.Second)

    opsFinal := atomic.LoadUint64(&ops)
    fmt.Println("ops:", opsFinal)
}
```

without the `runtime.Gosched()` (`go run conc.go`) and the program never exited even when I reduced the loop from 50 to 1.

**Question:**

What happens under the hood after the call to `atomic.AddUint64` that it is necessary to call `runtime.Gosched`? And how does `runtime.Gosched` fixes this? I did not find any hint to such a thing in [`sync/atomic`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic)'s documentation.

Comment: Maybe the best advice would be: Use neither `sync/atomic` nor `runtime.Gosched`. The atomic operations in `snyc/atomic` are there because **sometimes** atomic operations provide significant performance gain. Most user will not need these and most should not use atomic operations as this quickly becomes complicated. Keep away from such low-level stuff.

Comment: The call to `Gosched` has _abolutely_ _nothing_ to do with `atomic.AddUint64`. You could substitute `i++` for the AddUint64. It just happens, that the inner loop is too tight and won't yield to the scheduler, but this has nothing to do with atomic operations. See David's answer for details.

Comment: @Volker, I'm afraid, `i++` isn't a preemption point. Back in the day, they happened to be at syscalls and calls to `C` but since some version (1.4 ?) normal Go function calls also serve as preemption points, so something like `func(){return}()` should suffice (well, unless may be such a call could be completely optimized away).

Comment: @kostix Sorry, I was unclear: You could substitute `i++` for `AddUint64` (not for `GoSched`). This would be racy, but as you stated, it would not allow preemption.

Answer (score 5):

This is how [cooperative multithreading](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week11/32.html) works. If one thread remains ready to run, it continues to run and other threads don't. Explicit and implicit pre-emption points are used to allow other threads to run. If your thread has a loop that it stays in for lots of time with no implicit pre-emption points, you'll starve other threads if you don't add an explicit pre-emption point.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13108469/721269) has much more information about when Go uses cooperative multithreading.

Comment: The answer you mention is correct but as of Go 1.5, GOMAXPROCS is automatically set to how many CPU cores you have.

Comment: @wldsvc That doesn't change anything. You still have cooperative multithreading. If, for example, GOMAXPROCS is 8 and you have 9 threads, none of which hit any pre-emption points, one of the threads will still be starved. It's not about how many threads you have but about how you switch what tasks the threads are doing. (Also, there are still machines with only one core. Virtual machines with one core aren't even uncommon.)