# Goroutine example explaination needed

Tags: go, goroutine

I've just started to learn Go and follow a tutorial which contains the following example on goroutines:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
)

func say(s string) {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        runtime.Gosched()
        fmt.Println(s)
    }
}

func main() {
    go say("world") // create a new goroutine
    say("hello")    // current goroutine
}
```

it states that "**runtime.Gosched()** *means let the CPU execute other goroutines, and come back at some point.*". The following output is given below the example:

```
hello
world
hello
world
hello
world
hello
world
hello
```

However when I run this example on my machine with `go run` I get

```
hello
world
world
world
world
world
hello
hello
hello
hello
```

my version of Go is `go version go1.6 darwin/amd64`.

Actually I don't understand either result! Why isn't it just

```
hello
```

? As I understand Go programs quit after the last statement of the program is executed, so I'd think that after `say()` is run as a goroutine and its execution is delayed, the program executes next `say()` as an ordinary function, print "hello" and then exit.

So which result is the correct one and why?

Comment: Check this out. [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107958/what-exactly-does-runtime-gosched-do)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First output is the one that will be generated by a single core machine. The second could be generated by a multicore one.

`say` is a function with a for loop inside, that iterates 5 times. It indeed is an ordinary function but there is a call to `Gosched` in it. What `Gosched` does is, it tell the runtime to pause executing the current goroutine and instead start another waiting goroutine. This is called *yielding*.

**Explaining first output**

This is the output you can expect to get in a single core machine. Going step by step,

`go say("world")`

At this step the runtime starts executing the `say("world")` call on a seperate goroutine and continue the main goroutine. But the machine only has a single core. So both goroutines cannot run parrallely. The new goroutine (say `gr A`) has to wait until the running main goroutine(say `gr B`) finishes or *pauses*(yeilds). So it waits. Main goroutine starts executing `say("hello")`

Now while going through the `say` function of `gr B` runtime meets `runtime.Gosched()`

The `Gosched` call is like *pausing*. It tells the runtime to pause me and shedule an other goroutine that is waiting. So the runtime schedules the `gr A`. It begins from where it was waiting, which is,

`say("world")`

Now `gr A` executes until it meets its own `runtime.Gosched()`. `gr A` pauses. `gr B` wakes up and start running from where it left. The statement after `runtime.Gosched()` is to print "hello". So "hello" is printed. `gr B` continues and enters the next iteration of its for loop. Meets `Gosched`. Pauses. `gr A` restarts. Prints "world". I think you can see how this goes on for 5 times until it prints the given output.

**Explaining the second output**

If your machine has more than one core, the goroutines can run in parallel. Yours is an output you get when it does.

Now when `go say("world")` is called `gr A` does not have to wait until `gr B` finishes. It can immediately start on an other core. So when `Gosched` is called there could be no waiting goroutines. If the current one pauses it will immediately start on a different core.

So in a multicore machine you can't guarantee the order the words are printed. If you run the program many times I think you will see other orders as well.

You can set GOMAXPROCs to 1 and see how the program would run on a single core machine.

```
func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)

    go say("world") // create a new goroutine
    say("hello")    // current goroutine
}
```

Then you will see the first output.

Comment: if I have enough cores and the execution flow meets `Gosched()` there may actually be no waiting, did I get it right? So `Gosched()` is a kind of saying "if you can continue running otherwise you may switch to another goroutine here"?

Comment: I think it will always pause the current goroutine. And pick a waiting goroutine to execute. If the only waiting goroutine is the one it just paused, then it will be picked again. So basically what you said.