# Go Tour #10: What is the use of that done channel in the crawler solution

Tags: go

In [this solution](https://go.googlesource.com/tour/+/refs/heads/release-branch.go1.4/solutions/webcrawler.go) to the [tenth slide](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/10) of the concurrency Go tour I have a question regarding the following section:

```
done := make(chan bool)
for i, u := range urls {
    fmt.Printf("-> Crawling child %v/%v of %v : %v.\n", i, len(urls), url, u)
    go func(url string) {
        Crawl(url, depth-1, fetcher)
        done <- true
    }(u)
}
for i, u := range urls {
    fmt.Printf("<- [%v] %v/%v Waiting for child %v.\n", url, i, len(urls), u)
    <-done
}
fmt.Printf("<- Done with %v\n", url)
```

What purpose does adding and removing true from the the channel `done` and running the two separate for loops have? Is it just to block until the go routine finishes? I know this is an example exercise, but doesn't that kind of defeat the point of spinning out a new thread in the first place?

Why can't you just call `go Crawl(url, depth-1, fetcher)` without the 2nd for loop and the `done` channel? Is it because of the shared memory space for all the variables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first `for` loop schedules multiple goroutines to run and is iterating over a slice of urls.

The second loop blocks on each url, waiting until its corresponding `Crawl()` invocation has completed. All the `Crawl()`ers will run and do their work in parallel and block exiting until the main thread has a chance to receive a message on the `done` channel for each url.

In my opinion, a better way to implement this is to use a [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup). This code could log the wrong thing depending on how long each `Crawl()` invocation takes unless `fetcher` locks.

If you want to be sure of the url that finished `Crawl()`ing, you could change the type of the done channel to `string` and send the `url` instead of `true` upon a `Crawl()` completion. Then, we could receive the `url` in the second loop.

Example:

```
done := make(chan string)
for _, u := range urls {
    fmt.Printf("-> Crawling %s\n", u)
    go func(url string) {
        Crawl(url, depth-1, fetcher)
        done <- url
    }(u)
}
for range urls {
    fmt.Printf("<- Waiting for next child\n")
    u := <-done
    fmt.Printf("  Done... %s\n", u)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I found the WaitGroup in my own research, its similar to some concurrency concepts I am familiar with from Python. However, I thought I should try and understand how to solve the exercise using only things mentioned in the previous lessons.

Followup to your explanation, are you saying that each Crawler has it's own channel associated with it? That would make a lot more sense, and would explain why theres another loop that corresponds to each Crawler. I as under the impression all variables were in a shared space and thinking there was just one channel total.

Comment: @leif Each crawler doesn't have it's own channel - there is only one channel. After each `Crawl` function is executed the `url` is sent via the same channel. You may want to read up a bit more and do a few exercises on channels. The Go Programming Language, by Donovan and Kernighan is a good book to read.

Comment: Thanks @Ravi, I was replying to the unedited version of Blaskovicz's post which is now more clear that there is only one channel as I originally thought. I will check out the book you recommended, thanks!